# Is it possible to customize Jpa Repository with inheritance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Let's say that i have two Classes: Subject and Client, Subject is base-class.

```
@Entity
public class Client extends Subject
```

Now i want to add customized Jpa base interface, so methods will be accessible in  subinterfaces:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SubjectRepository <T extends Subject> extends 
JpaRepository<T, Long>, CustomSubjectRepository<T> {}
```

**CustomSubjectRepository** looks like:

```
public interface CustomSubjectRepository<T extends Subject> {
    void saveEncrypted(T subject);
}
```

I need implementation so i declare class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CustomSubjectRepositoryImpl<T extends Subject> implements 
CustomSubjectRepository<T> {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public void saveEncrypted(T subject) {
    //implementation
}
}
```

Then wanted to create **ClientRepository** and inherit from **SubjectRepository** to have access to **saveEncrypted** method.

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends SubjectRepository<Client> {
}
```

But when it comes to compile i get:

> Error creating bean with name 'clientRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.path.repositories.CustomSubjectRepository.saveEncrypted(com.path.models.Subject)! No property saveEncrypted found for type Client!

Comment: Your title doesn't match with question statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending the interface, this way Spring will try to  create a query named `saveEncrypted` instead of using the customized method.

I believe the best solution is to extend the class `CustomSubjectRepositoryImpl`.

```
@Repository
public class ClientRepository extends CustomSubjectRepositoryImpl<Client> {
}
```